# How to loop through XML-nodes and validate if values exists?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, domdocument

I have through an API fetched my data as an XML, and I wish to cycle through nodes (there are several of the same type) and add them to certain fields/a table.

Example from the XML-file:

```xml
<HistRating
  xmlns="">
  <EndrAr>2020</EndrAr>
  <EndrMnd>7</EndrMnd>
  <Rating>A</Rating>
</HistRating>
<HistRating
  xmlns="">
  <EndrAr>2019</EndrAr>
  <EndrMnd>6</EndrMnd>
  <Rating>A</Rating>
</HistRating>
```

I have tried the following format (at this point the XML I need is in a string in xmlDoc `xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")`. Fully aware that this is not a really "sexy" way to write it, but I'm new at this game:

```
Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("EndrAr")
Range("G1").Value = nodeXML(1).Text
Range("H1").Value = nodeXML(2).Text
Range("I1").Value = nodeXML(3).Text

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("EndrMnd")
Range("G2").Value = nodeXML(1).Text
Range("H2").Value = nodeXML(2).Text
Range("I2").Value = nodeXML(3).Text

Set nodeXML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Rating")
Range("G3").Value = nodeXML(1).Text
Range("H3").Value = nodeXML(2).Text
Range("I3").Value = nodeXML(3).Text
```

This works great as long as all three items are there. Unfortunately that is not given. If it is a new company i.e. (3) wont exist (there is one line per year above), and I would like to either set the cell to Blank or `No value` or something.

The result from when I run the above code:

[image: Image of range G1:I3 filled with info]

But if I try to add a line 4 to test what happens if value does not exists I get the following (for obvious reasons)

[image: Image of error message "Object variable or With block cariable not set"]

**What I would love some help with is:**

- Can I by some "magic" add a `ifmissing` (tried it, but could not get it to work)?
- Other ways to add a `if variable is not found, input following into cell`
- Or are there a complete different way I should have solved this?

This is to add accounting data from last `X` available years (where X is ie 4, or less if not 4 is available) from 30 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by querying all of the `HistRating` elements, then loop over that collection:

```vb
Const MAX_YEARS As Long = 4
Dim ratings, rating, c As Range, i as Long

Set c= Range("A1")
Set ratings = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("HistRating")
For Each rating in ratings
    c.offset(0, i) = rating.getElementsByTagName("EndrAr")(0).Text
    c.offset(1, i) = rating.getElementsByTagName("EndrMnd")(0).Text
    c.offset(2, i) = rating.getElementsByTagName("Rating")(0).Text
    i = i + 1
    If i >= MAX_YEARS Then Exit For 'exit if processed enough nodes
Next rating
```

Comment: Wow Tim, thank you! This seems to be exactly what I needed! Do you know of a way to set a Max amount of runs? The Xml may in some cases return 10 years, but I would like to limit it to as many as possible, but no more than 4.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an Error trapping Function. Note in the code below we choose not to use the returned boolean.

```
Dim myTest as String
.
.
TryReadingXmlNode nodeXML,1, myText
Range("G1").Value = myText
.   
.

Public Function TryReadingXmlNode(ByVal ipNode as object, ByVal ipIndex as Long, ByRef opText as string) as boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    opText=ipNode.Item(ipIndex).Text
    TryReadingXmlNode=Len(opText)>0
    If err.number>0 then opText="NoValue"
    on Error Goto 0
 
End Function
```

Comment: Fine that you dealt with the question in OP how to provide for `"IsMissing"` as a possible solution. - Personally I'd prefer to check for an existing node (before referencing its `.Text` value) via `If Not ipNode(ipIndex) Is Nothing Then` ... `End If`. This seems to me the more *direct* way than to wait for a raising error (trying `ipNode.Item(ipIndex).Text`); but generally it's nothing bad to use this approach :-)

Comment: That's a good approach **if** you can test for nothing.