# Import XML data using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, msxml

I'm trying to import specific data from and XML file to an Excel sheet.

The code I'm using is this.

```
Dim oXMLFile As New DOMDocument60
Dim books As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim results() As String
Dim i As Integer, booksUBound As Integer
Dim book As IXMLDOMNode, title As IXMLDOMNode, author As IXMLDOMNode

oXMLFile.Load "C:\example.xml"

Set books = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/OUT_MESSAGE/LINES/OUT_MESSAGE_LINE")
booksUBound = books.Length - 1

ReDim results(booksUBound, 1)

For i = 0 To booksUBound
    Set book = books(i) 
    Set title = book.SelectSingleNode("C00")
    If Not title Is Nothing Then results(i, 0) = title.Text
Next

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ActiveSheet
wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells(books.Length, 2)) = results
```

Which works with this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OUT_MESSAGE>
 <LINES>
  <OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
   <C00>1231231</C00>
   <C01>3213213</C01>
  </OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
  <OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
   <C00>1231234</C00>
   <C01>3213214</C01>
  </OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
 </LINES>
</OUT_MESSAGE>
```

My problem is that my XML file looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OUT_MESSAGE xmlns="urn:randomaddress-com:schema:test_out_message" xmlns:xsi="http://www.randomurl.com/123">
 <LINES>
  <OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
   <C00>1231231</C00>
   <C01>3213213</C01>
  </OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
  <OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
   <C00>1231234</C00>
   <C01>3213214</C01>
  </OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
 </LINES>
</OUT_MESSAGE>
```

Which I originally thought I could simply get to work by replacing

```
Set books = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/OUT_MESSAGE/LINES/OUT_MESSAGE_LINE")
```

With

```
Set books = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("/OUT_MESSAGE xmlns='urn:randomaddress-com:schema:test_out_message' xmlns:xsi='http://www.randomurl.com/123'/LINES/OUT_MESSAGE_LINE")
```

But that gives me a runtime error.

If anyone know what changes I have to do to the original code that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make what work? What are you trying to do? Get the text from the tags?

Comment: You need to show more of your actual XML - we can't tell you anything from a single opening tag.  However it looks like you're dealing with "namespaces" so you need to let `oXMLFile` know about those - it doesn't happen automatically.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901392/nodes-in-xml-does-not-appear-to-be-identified-utilizable/64902141#64902141

Comment: @TimWilliams I added how my XML compares to the other one. The other post looks like it would work, I'm trying that.

Comment: It would be more useful if you could post a sample of your actual XML - if you're not familiar with XML then we can't be confident that your "book" example reflects what's actually your real structure. If the content is confidential then just obfuscate it, but keep the structure. Also if you could post the code you tried, instead of the code from the previous post, that would also help.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I updated my example XML and did the changes in the code that I have done, it is basically just the SelectNodes part and the names of the tags to find

Comment: Is it just the C00,C01 tags you want to extract or all of them ?

Comment: @CDP1802 just the C00 and C01

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```vba
Dim xDoc, nodes, oNode

Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

'Note: added an `x=` to the default namespace so we can reference it later
xDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
                 "xmlns:x='urn.randomaddress.com.schema.test_out_message'"

xDoc.LoadXML Sheet2.Range("A4").Value 'load XML from sheet

'use the "x" prefix we added above
Set nodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/x:OUT_MESSAGE/x:LINES/x:OUT_MESSAGE_LINE")
Debug.Print nodes.Length  '  = 1

For Each oNode In nodes
    Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("x:C00").nodeTypedValue
    Debug.Print oNode.SelectSingleNode("x:OBJSTATE").nodeTypedValue
    'etc
Next oNode
```

using this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OUT_MESSAGE xmlns="urn.randomaddress.com.schema.test_out_message" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.randomurl.com/123">
 <LINES>
  <OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
   <C00>321312</C00>
   <C01>12312312</C01>
   <OBJSTATE>Posted</OBJSTATE>
   <OBJEVENTS>Accept^Reject^</OBJEVENTS>
   <STATE>Posted</STATE>
  </OUT_MESSAGE_LINE>
 </LINES>
</OUT_MESSAGE>
```

Comment: How do I export the results from yours?

Comment: You would write code to put the results into cells rather than use Debug.Print, or use the array approach in your posted code.

Comment: When I add the array approach from my original code to your code, with the necessary changes, it doesnt work.